# How to align paragraph center by phpword?

Tags: php, phpword

I used phpword plugin to create word files in my project ,but I have a problem that the paragraph didn't align center ,for example :
[image]

But I want like this :
[image]

How can I do ?

```
$textrun = $section->createTextRun(array('widowControl'=>'true'));
$textrun->addText('There is a',array('size'=>13));
$textrun->addImage('563803062838d1446511366.gif');
```

Comment: can you paste the code used to generate the word.

Answer (score 0):

no promises but this give you some values yo 'play' with

```
$textrun->addImage(
    '563803062838d1446511366.gif',
    array(
        'width' => 100, //set to match image
        'height' => 100, //set to match image
        'marginTop' => 5, //my guess play with this value
        'marginLeft' => 0,
        'wrappingStyle' => 'behind'
    )
);
```

you could also consider adding white space to the image to manipulate its location

Comment: "**it**" ?? There are multiple options there, your not helping us help you

Comment: I mean that I used the codes you gived me to create images  ,but it didn't align center also.